# malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]

Tags: elasticsearch

The original query looks like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "doc",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "id": [
                                                713
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "created": {
                                                "lte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "expires": {
                                                "gte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "doc_type": "item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "have_prices": true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_folder": true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "folder"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "is_folder": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "title_low.order": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
   "size": 1000 
}
```

And I got some result

```
"hits": {
        "total": 19,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "prices",
                "_type": "doc",
                "_id": "item-6800004",
                "_score": null,
                "_routing": "1",
                "_source": {
                    "id": 6800004,
                    "id_pricedoc": 713,
                    "title": "\"водка №1\" 1",
                    "title_low": "\"водка №1\" 1",
                    "supplier": {
                        "id": 7831,
                        "type": null
                    },
                    "supplier_nom": {
                        "id": 1375697,
                        "market_nom": {
                            "id": null
                        },
                        "codes": null,
                        "sup_code": "7a6713a5-73c1-3acb-9b62-9e38b2314dce",
                        "manufacturer": {
                            "id": null,
                            "title": null
                        }
                    },
                    "is_folder": false,
                    "folder": null,
                    "path": null,
                    "pricedoc_created": "2016-03-21",
                    "prices": [
                        {
                            "currency": "RUR",
                            "id_offer": 15735967,
                            "id_prcknd": 167,
                            "value": "391.50"
                        }
                    ],
                    "have_prices": true,
                    "market": {
                        "title": null,
                        "uuid": null,
                        "folder": null,
                        "path": null
                    },
                    "_join_field_name": "doc_type",
                    "doc_type": {
                        "name": "item",
                        "parent": "doc-713"
                    }
                },
                "sort": [
                    0,
                    "\"водка №1\" 1"
                ]
            }
```

Now I also would like get result where "id_prcknd": 167

Modified query looks like this

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "doc",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "id": [
                                                713
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "created": {
                                                "lte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "expires": {
                                                "gte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "doc_type": "item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "have_prices": true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_folder": true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "folder"
                }
            }
        },
        "nested": {
                "path": "prices",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "prices.id_prcknd": 167
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "is_folder": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "title_low.order": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
   "size": 1000 
}}
```

But I got an error Elasticsearch malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]
Where am I wrong?
I wanna match objects where "id_prcknd": 167
The stackoverflow says the I post mostly the code, but it's because of large queries in elastic search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What Elasticsearch was trying to say is that it did not expect to see other keys  but `bool` in the dictionary (the value under `"query"`).

In your example code you have something like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {...},
                {...},
                {...}
            ],
            "must_not": {...},
        "nested": {...}, // this should go under "must"
        "sort": [...],   // this should go on the same level as "query"
        "size": 1000     // this should go on the same level as "query"
    }
}
```

`"bool"` here refers to a [`bool`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query, and should be the only key in the dictionary.

What you should do is to move `"nested"` into its own dictionary and the fourth element of the `must` array (if I understood the logic of what you are trying to achieve correctly). Please note that also `"sort"` and `"size"` should be moved - this time, to the same level as `"query"`.

The full query will look like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "has_parent": {
                        "parent_type": "doc",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "terms": {
                                            "id": [
                                                713
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "created": {
                                                "lte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "range": {
                                            "expires": {
                                                "gte": "now/d"
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "term": {
                        "doc_type": "item"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "have_prices": true
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "is_folder": true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "nested": {
                        "path": "prices",
                        "query": {
                            "bool": {
                                "must": [
                                    {
                                        "match": {
                                            "prices.id_prcknd": 167
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not": {
                "exists": {
                    "field": "folder"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "is_folder": {
                "order": "desc"
            }
        },
        {
            "title_low.order": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ],
    "size": 1000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your json is incorrect:     Error:Expecting closing } at end[Code 22, Structure 183]

Use a json validator (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) for example.

Comment: You are right, I didn't copied it, I edited the answer, thanks